# SQL doesn't return expected column data in CASE statement (Oracle BI)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following snippet for a column (using Oracle BI):

```
CASE 
    WHEN  
         IFNULL(YEAR("- Supplier Profile"."Inactive Date"), 0)  > 0 
            THEN  "- General"."Last Updated By" 
            ELSE 'BLAH BLAH BLAH'  
         END
```

If there is a date, it does not pull back the person (Last Updated By). It also does not show `"BLAH BLAH BLAH"`.

If I replace `"- General"."Last Updated By"` with `'SOMETHING'` then `'SOMETHING'` is displayed without issue.

If I remove the whole snippet and replace it with just `"- General"."Last Updated By"` then that brings back the person just fine.

If I issue this query, it returns the people just fine

```
CASE
   WHEN
      1=1
   THEN
      " - General"."Last Updated By" 
   ELSE
      'N/A' 
END
```

In fact, if I do the following, stuff gets returned. It looks as though there's a problem with comparing a date field and outputting a char field.

```
CASE 
    WHEN  
         IFNULL(YEAR("- Supplier Profile"."Inactive Date"), 0)  > 0 
            THEN  "- General"."Last Updated By" 
            ELSE 'BLAH BLAH BLAH'  
         END
```

Any reason?

Comment: How Last Updated By defined?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking

Comment: It looks like it's a part of a larger query. You should make a small, complete example, that illustrates your issue which we then can help you with - or with which you can debug your issue much easier. Right now we're left guessing based on lack of information.

Comment: Unfortunately due to restrictions - I am now allowed to. I believe I have given a lot of information.

Comment: That's why I said you should make a small, complete example so you don't need to post large possible secret code snippets. That way you can isolate the issue, it's easier for us to help with as we can use fiddle etc - and possible you even find the issue with the syntax yourself :)

Comment: Why are you not simply checking `"- Supplier Profile"."Inactive Date" IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger - was just going to do that - great minds!

Comment: CASE doesn't allow inconsistent return types in the data. Is `BLAH BLAH BLAH` a date in your actual query?

Comment: What are `IFNULL` and `YEAR`? There are no Oracle SQL functions with those names. Maybe they are part of the BI tool or something?

Comment: @Ben the return types are both CHAR, it's just the comparison is against a date. Also, IFNULL appears in MySQL but it is part of the Oracle BI tool that I am using

Comment: @Ben there does seem to be something in that - can you suggest something for reference for me to look into?

Comment: [_"For both simple and searched CASE expressions, all of the return_exprs must either have the same data type"_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96)

Comment: The returned expressions have the same data type in my case

Comment: "it does not pull back the person (Last Updated By). It also does not show "BLAH BLAH BLAH" - what _does_ it show? NULL? That case statement can only show one or the other. Maybe one of them is NULL. Have you checked?

Comment: I have checked and that is not the case